# MVC3 and Ajax error "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter ..."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, routes

This is driving me nuts!

I have a view that is populated using Ajax using the script below.

```
function loadAcquisitions() {
    var description = $("input#searchDescription").val();
    var startDate = $("input#searchStartDate").val();
    var endDate = $("input#searchEndDate").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Acquisition/Find",
        data: { searchDescription: description, searchStartDate: startDate, searchEndDate: endDate },
        success: function (jsonresults) {
            $("tbody#acquisitionContent").find("tr").remove().end();

            var pageCount = parseInt(jsonresults.length / pageSize);
            var startItemIndex = currentPageIndex * pageSize;
            var itemsToDisplay = pageSize + startItemIndex;

            if ((jsonresults.length - startItemIndex) < pageSize) {
                itemsToDisplay = jsonresults.length - startItemIndex + pageSize;
            }

            for (var i = startItemIndex; i < itemsToDisplay; i++) {
                $("tbody#acquisitionContent").append('<tr>' +
                    '<td><a href="/Acquisition/Edit/' + jsonresults[i].AcquisitionID + '">Edit</a></td>' +
                    '<td>' + jsonresults[i].AcquisitionDescription + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + jsonresults[i].AcquisitionDate + '</td>' +
                    '<td>$' + jsonresults[i].AcquisitionCost + '</td>' +
                    '<td>$' + jsonresults[i].InstallationCost + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="last">$' + jsonresults[i].DeliveryCost + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>');
            }

            $('#pageTitle').text('Page ' + (currentPageIndex + 1) + ' of ' + pageCount);
        },
        error: function (c, b, a) {
            alert(a);
        }
    });
}
```

Please note that the link is generated using the line:

```
'<td><a href="/Acquisition/Edit/' + jsonresults[i].AcquisitionID + '">Edit</a></td>'
```

The link tag appears to be generated correctly and is in the form of

```
/Acquisition/Edit/123
```

In the controller, I have the following function called 'Edit' which looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int acquisitionID)
{
    Acquisition acquisition = Acquisition.Get(acquisitionID);
    return View(acquisition);
}
```

Then, in the global.asax I have a route defined for 'Edit' that looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EditAcquisition",
    "{controller}/{action}/{acquisitionID}",
    new { controller = "Acquisition", action = "Edit"}
    );
```

I've tried changing the 'Edit' function in the controller to accept a nullable int (int?) acquisitionID which gets rid of the error - but doesn't change the fact that a null is being passed into the controllers 'Edit' function from the link generated by the Ajax code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**Update:**

When I update the global.asax and add 'acquisitionID' as a parameter like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EditAcquisition",
    "{controller}/{action}/{acquisitionID}",
    new { controller = "Acquisition", action = "Edit", acquisitionID = 0 }
    );
```

the application behaves very differently in that the navigation links now all have 'Index' appended to them.

```
/Acquisition/
```

becomes

```
/Acquisition/Index
```

**Update:**

Here is the RegisterRoutes method of the global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "EditProperty",
        "{controller}/{action}/{propertyID}",
        new {controller = "Property", action = "Edit"}
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "EditAssignee",
        "{controller}/{action}/{assigneeID}",
        new {controller = "Assignee", action = "Edit"}
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "EditAcquisition",
        "{controller}/{action}/{acquisitionID}",
        new {controller = "Acquisition", action = "Edit"}
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}
```

Comment: can you show all your routes (*in the order you have them defined*) because it seems like another route is matching the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "EditProperty",
        "{controller}/{action}/{propertyID}",
        new {controller = "Property", action = "Edit"}
        );
```

Matches every other route.. (*since they all have the same pattern of `/controller/action/id`*)

The values provided by `new {controller = "Property", action = "Edit"}` are the default, not the allowed ones..

so any url in the form `/somecontroller/someaction/someid` will be matched by that, and the id will be called `propertyID`.

That is why you receive no `acquisitionID`

Either just keep that one route only and name the `propertyID` to something generic like `id` and use that in your method, or use `constraints` for all your routes that have identical pattern

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "EditProperty",
        "{controller}/{action}/{propertyID}",
        new {controller = "Property", action = "Edit"},
        new {controller = "Property", action="Edit"} // constraint
        );
```

Comment: That was it ... I now see what the problem was.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For my routes, I always include the `URLParameter` setting:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "EditAcquisition",
                "{controller}/{action}/{acquisitionID}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Acquisition",
                    action = "Edit",
                    acquisitionID = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

which works even if the parameter is not nullable int. I've also done

```
acquisitionID = 0
```

I'm afraid I can't really explain why it works though.

**EDIT**

Something else to try

```
"EditAcquisition",
 "Acquisition/Edit/{acquisitionID}",
 new
 {
     controller = "Acquisition",
     action = "Edit",
     acquisitionID = UrlParameter.Optional
 }
```

So the URL is being matched against the second parameter, URL, not the third, which are the defaults.

Comment: Sorry - I just tried that and now I've got some additional problems that I'll add to the question.

Comment: @Andy can you post the whole routes section of your global.asax - and any in the Areas section if you have that. I suspect that another route is being matched before the `EditAcquisition` one is.

Comment: I've added them to the question